# Merging multiple JObjects in a list - Json4s

Tags: java, json, scala, list

I am trying to merge together multiple JObjects to become one single JObject. I have a list of JObjects that I am trying to iterate over and merge each of them into one object, essentially creating one large json object.

The below works fine, however when in a list it doesn't work. I know im doing something wrong but not sure what?

```
val obj1: JObject = RancherHelper.convertToJObject(containers.head)
val obj2: JObject = RancherHelper.convertToJObject(containers(1))
val obj3: JObject = RancherHelper.convertToJObject(containers(2))

val x: JObject = obj1 merge obj2 merge obj3
```

This doesn't work:

```
def mergeJObjects(containers: List[JObject]): JObject = {
    val fullJsonObject: JObject = JObject()
    val singleObject = for{
      container <- containers
      fullObj = fullJsonObject.merge(container)
    } yield fullObj

    fullJsonObject
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of mapping over the list, fold it:

```
def mergeJObjects(containers: List[JObject]): JObject = {
  containers.foldLeft(JObject())((merged, next) => merged.merge(next))
}
```

What you have written above is syntactic sugar for this:

```
val fullJsonObject = JObject()
val singleObject = containers.map { container =>
  val fullObj = fullJsonObject.merge(container)
  fullObj
}
fullJsonObject
```

Essentially, you are mapping over the containers list, and for each container you are merging it with an empty JSON object (`fullJsonObject`). Therefore `singleObject` is no different from `containers`; it is a list of your original JSON objects. Moreover, since `fullJsonObject` is an *immutable* empty `JObject`, you are simply returning the empty JSON object at the end of your method.